# dedupe mysql table but ignore empty values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that uploads csv files into a mysql database.

The database has several columns. Among these columns is an 'email' field. I wrote some mysql that would remove rows that contained duplicate values in the email column. Below is the mysql:

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE new_table as SELECT * FROM auto WHERE 1 GROUP BY email";

mysql_query($sql, $conn);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM new_table");
list($number) = mysql_fetch_row($query);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auto");
list($number2) = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$result = $number2 - $number;
mysql_query("DROP TABLE auto");
mysql_query("RENAME TABLE new_table TO auto");
```

The code works, it removes duplicate values.

**Problem:**

It removes rows that contain no values. So it assumes that two or more emails values that are empty are duplicates and removes they're rows.

**Question:**

How do I tell mysql to ignore empty values.

Thanks for the help.

**Edit**

The where is my database table. One table.
The when is when I execute the code. I plan on putting in a php file to be executed on demand.
The result I expect is a mysql table without duplicate emails.

Comment: can you explain better? can you tell where, when and what is the result that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work for a one-time alteration, by allowing NULL in email, and adding a UNIQUE constraint:

```
-- set empties to NULL
UPDATE tablename SET email = NULL WHERE LENGTH(email)=0;
-- drop all rows violating the UNIQUE constraint on email:
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE (email);
```

Comment: I get this error when I run those sql commands "ALTER IGNORE test ADD UNIQUE (email);"

Error #1064 syntax. It points to the email value

Comment: Oops, `TABLE` should be in there, editing now (BTW: you are working on a testdb / have backups in case it doesn't work like you expect?)

Comment: Thanks for the help BTW. I got another error though. ALTER IGNORE TABLE test ADD UNIQUE (email);
Error:#1062 Duplicate entry 'qwe' for key 'email'.

Keep in mind this table has duplicate values under email. so in thiss case 'qwe' was the dupe value I put in there.

Comment: Hm, the `IGNORE` part is there to ignore that error (i.e: discard the row that violates), see also the second remark in 'Usage Notes" at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html. Are you sure those are errors rather then warnings? Might have something to do with the mode the server is in, although I wouldn't know what.